# tcolorbox in widetext environment of RevTeX

Tags: tcolorbox, revtex

I want to use tcolorbox in widetext environment of the APS LaTeX template, however, the tcolorbox in the environment displays as twocolumn, not one column. How can I solve the problem?
[image]

Here's is my MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[reprint,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}
\title{NEGF Method Report}
\author{Axia}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
    A derivation to the article ``Time-dependent transport in interacting and noninteracting resonant-tunneling systems'' which has been published in 1994 on PRB. This article especially introduced the NEGF method.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\section{APPLICABILITY TO EXPERIMENTS}

\section{THEORETICAL TOOLS AND THE MODEL}
\subsection{Baym-Kadanoff-Keldysh nonequilibrium techniques}
\begin{widetext}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{widetext}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `tcolorbox` uses `\columnwidth`. Just specify you want `\textwidth` instead.

```
\documentclass[reprint,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}
\title{NEGF Method Report}
\author{Axia}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
A derivation to the article ``Time-dependent transport in interacting 
and noninteracting resonant-tunneling systems'' which has been published 
in 1994 on PRB. This article especially introduced the NEGF method.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\section{APPLICABILITY TO EXPERIMENTS}

\lipsum[2]

\section{THEORETICAL TOOLS AND THE MODEL}

\lipsum[3]

\subsection{Baym-Kadanoff-Keldysh nonequilibrium techniques}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{widetext}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]
\lipsum[1][1-3]        
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{widetext}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I filled with lipsum text just in order to make the picture more realistic.

[image]

Comment: With your help, I've solved my question. Thank you very much